# Declare a symbol immediately after another in C

Tags: c, gcc, clang

I'm looking to export a symbol that points to the end of a global array, like so:

```
char my_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
char my_array_end[] = &my_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
```

However the above doesn't compile:

```
prog.c:5:28: error: invalid initializer
     char my_array_end[] = &my_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
                            ^
```

The below compiles and works perfectly, but feels a tad brittle – not to mention non-portable. Is there any way to achieve this in C?

```
__asm__ (
    ".global my_array;"
    ".section .lbss,\"aw\",@nobits;"
    ".type my_array, @object;"
    ".size my_array, " ARRAY_SIZE ";"
    "my_array:;"
    ".zero " ARRAY_SIZE ";"
    ".global my_array_end;"
    "my_array_end:;"
);
extern char my_array[ARRAY_SIZE];
extern char my_array_end[];
```

Comment: `char * my_array_end = my_array + ARRAY_SIZE;` Why this would be useful I don't know.

Comment: `char my_array_end[0] = ...` you are trying to assign(initialize) to a zero-sized character array. (with a pointer) Maybe your intention was `char *my_array_end...`

Comment: @AlexP That is exporting a symbol called `my_array_end` which points to a pointer in the `.data` section which points to the end of the array. That does not solve my problem.

Comment: @Alec - *That does not solve my problem* - why ? what is exactly problem ? why symbol must direct point to array end, but say to pointer for array end. or say why export simply function, which return pointer to array end `void* fn(){ return my_array+ARRAY_SIZE; }` not a solution ?

Comment: C doesn't have zero-length arrays (except for flexible array members in structs). What is `my_array_end[0]` supposed to be for? Since you can't access the elements, it can only be used as a pointer, and that's what `char *my_array_end = &my_array[ARRAY_SIZE];` declares.

Comment: I've also seen custom linker scripts used to add labels if the objects are globally visible...but that's worse than your inline-asm solution.

Comment: @RbMm: While not explicitly stated I assume that the intent of the question is to declare an opaque array/type local to a compilation unit while exporting its end or size via the linker to remove a layer of indirection and thereby ameliorate a performance hit. Something which, as demonstrated, is generally possible in assembly code. I know of no portable means of achieving this in C this, and for the most part would I advice that the hit in runtime or compilation time performance be taken here.

Comment: You could export the array size instead; then anything that needs the end can add it to the start

Comment: Whoops. missed the global export part of the problem. deleted spurious comments and an answer.

Comment: @doynax The purpose isn't performance as you specify, it's being able to resize an array in a relocatable without recompiling everything (as recompiling takes of the order of 2 hours and we frequently need to resize the array). I have a script to modify the size of a section and modify the `my_array_end` symbol appropriately. I was simply trying to avoid having to go a step further and modify the contents of the `.data` section.